# navigating from one page into another page in Cordova iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova

I'm super new in iOS Cordova now I'm struggling in navigating from one page into another . I just need need to know how the working of a page having a button called click and if I click that button it should go into next page. simple as like what we create like navigating viewController in iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("login").onclick = function () {
           window.location.href = "addProduct.html";
          };
        </script>
```

by this way you can navigate from one to another.